# Using PHP how to change text color if it equals today

Tags: php, date, text, colors

I have a field that I am trying to have the text show RED if the date matches today.  I also have to adjust for the server time being different than local time.

Here is what I have tried, which does not work and produces errors

```
global $data;
 $str = "<font color=";
if ($value=="date("m/d/Y")")
 $str.="red";
 $str.=">".$value."</b></font>";
 $value=$str;
```

---

```
global $data;
 $str = "<font color=";
if ($value==date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-8 hour"))
 $str.="red";
 $str.=">".$value."</b></font>";
 $value=$str;
```

Comment: You're missing `<b>` to match `</b>`

Comment: Use `date_default_timezone_set()` to adjust for different timezones.

Comment: Use CSS rather than `<font>` and `<b>`.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Your quoting is wrong on the `if ($value=="date("m/d/Y")")` line, that's probably why you're getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your question but if you mean you what to highlight the current date according to your server time minus 8 hours below could be your code.

```
<?php
 $dt_value = '08/22/2014';//sample date
 $today_minus8hrs = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('-8 hours'));

 if($dt_value == $today_minus8hrs){
   $color = 'red';
 }
?>

<p><font color="<?php echo $color?>" > <?php echo $dt_value?>  </font></p>
```

Comment: I am trying to change the font color to red if the date in the field is equal to today.  If the date is not today, then no change is needed

Comment: if you are referring to the server current local time change this line
From:
$today_minus8hrs = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('-8 hours'));
To:
$today = date('m/d/Y',time());
change the variable $today_minus8hrs to $today